# copying a directory tree to another location, with optional compression

Tags: compression, file-transfer

What I want to do is to copy a directory to anther position (on Linux), and compress some files (with a certain extension) with GZip on the destination, while other files are just copied. Could this be achieved by a one-liner with good efficiency? A lot of files are to be copies hence the more efficient the better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as an academic excersize:

```
set -e # abort on errors
find /source -print | while read object_name; do
  if [ -d "$object_name" ]; then
    mkdir -p /destination/$object_name
  else
    if echo "$object_name" | egrep "(txt|html|...)" >/dev/null # extensions you want to compress
      cat $object_name | gzip >/destination/${object_name}.gz
    else
      cp $object_name /destination/$object_name
    fi
  fi
  rm /source/$object_name # could comment this out to preserve the source if you have the space
done
```